# Can not post data through ajax when implements onchage() method

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, onchange

I try to post data using ajax with onchange method but the code doen't post data.

```
<input type="number" name="number" id="number" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'];?>" min="0" max="10" step="1" onchange="updateQ(<?php echo $row['quantity'];?>,<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>,<?php echo $row['date']; ?>,<?php echo $row['date']; ?>);">
```

Here is the script..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
        }
        function updateQ(quantity,cid,date,time){
           
          
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"cartqtyupd.php",
        data: 
        {  
           'qty' :quantity,
           'cid' :cid,
           'date' :date,
           'time' :time
        },
        success: function (response) 
        {
            alert("success");
         
           //window.location.href = "b.php";
           //next_page_url_here?key3=value3&key4=value4

        
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Please can you give some assitant to solve this problem. I tried so much times but couldnt get a solution. I read lot of stakoverflow problems and answers but I couldnt figure out what to do.

Comment: onchange="this.form.submit();" this navigates to php file and execute statements with the condition of if(!isset($_POST['submit'])). This is simple solution

Answer (score 2):

The values that you are passing as parameters to the `updateQ()` function are not properly formatted (missing quotes around string values). This will result in a syntax error when the JavaScript function tries to execute.

try this:

```
<input type="number" name="number" id="number" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'];?>" min="0" max="10" step="1" onchange="updateQ(this.value, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>, '<?php echo $row['date']; ?>', '<?php echo $row['time']; ?>');">
```

Comment: Thank you i solve it by simply onchange="this.form.submit()".